# How to align an image next to a search bar

Tags: html, css

So, I want to write a fan page for NerdHub (YouTube channel) and, I'm stuck because the "Search..." isn't in one line with the logo (of NerdHub).

Now as you can see it looks like this:

[image: Not aligned]

It should look like this:

[image: Correctly aligned]

I read a duplicate, but `display: inline-block;` didn't help me either.

All the files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Fl4MIf6otZq8w_xm17GD5NY9wbj5pM7G?usp=sharing

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Nerdhub</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="con">
    <div id="fel">
    </div>
</div>



<div id="asd">
    <form><input type="text" name="1" value="Search..."></form> 
</div>

<div id="img">
    <img src="nerdhub.jpg" width="200px">
</div>

<div id="adbytelekom">
    <p class="a">Remove Ads</p>
    <img src="adbytelekom.jpg">
    <div id="ad">
        <p class="a">Ads by Telekom</p>
    </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: black;
    }

    input[type="text"] {
        background-color: 4f4f4f;
        color: gray;
        padding: 5px 300px;
    }

    p.a {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    #img {
        text-align: top-left;
    }

    #asd {
        text-align: center;
    }

    #reklambytelekom {
        margin-top: 0px;
        text-align: right;
        margin-right: 100px;
        color: white;
    }

    #ad {
        margin-right: 115px;
    }

    #fel {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
 </style>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way is to use `flex` as above answer mentioned. You can align the items inside the box with `align-items` property. Simply add another div around the elements you wish to have on one line and give it following style:

```
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Also since you want to have logo to the left you should have it before the search bar.

```
<div id="wrapper">    
  <div id="img">
    <img src="nerdhub.jpg" width="200px">
  </div>

  <div id="asd">
    <form><input type="text" name="1" value="Search..."></form> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution will be to add `display:flex`. 
By default, flex renders its immediate children in a row.
I would encourage you to read more about flex properties [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp).

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

input[type="text"] {
  background-color: 4f4f4f;
  color: gray;
  padding: 5px 300px;
}

p.a {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#img {
  text-align: top-left;
}

#asd {
  text-align: center;
}

#reklambytelekom {
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 100px;
  color: white;
}

#ad {
  margin-right: 115px;
}

#fel {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.flex{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Nerdhub</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="con">
    <div id="fel">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex">
    <div id="img">
      <img src="nerdhub.jpg" width="200px">
    </div>

    <div id="asd">
      <form><input type="text" name="1" value="Search..."></form>
    </div>


    <div id="adbytelekom">
      <p class="a">Remove Ads</p>
      <img src="adbytelekom.jpg">
      <div id="ad">
        <p class="a">Ads by Telekom</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this one instead of your code...

<html>
<head>
    <title>Nerdhub</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="con">
        <div id="fel">
            <div id="img">
                <img src="nerdhub.jpg" width="200px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div id="asd">
        <form><input type="text" name="1" value="Keresés..."></form> 
    </div>



    <div id="reklambytelekom">
        <p class="a">Remove Ads</p>
        <img src="reklambytelekom.jpg">
        <div id="ad">
            <p class="a">Ads by Telekom</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--file:///D:/Don%C3%A1t/Programoz%C3%A1s/wamp/nerdhub.com/Nerdhub.html -->
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: black;
        }
        .con,#asd{float: left;}
        form{width: 80%;margin: 0 auto;}
        input[type="text"] {
            background-color: 4f4f4f;
            color: gray;
            padding: 5px 300px;
            margin: 15px 0;
        }

        p.a {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
        #img {
            text-align: top-left;
        }
        #asd {
            text-align: center;

        }

        #reklambytelekom {
            margin-top: 0px;
            text-align: right;
            margin-right: 100px;
            color: white;
        }

        #ad {
            margin-right: 115px;
        }
        .con > * {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        #fel {
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    </style>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add explanation to what you changed or why this is better than original. Also it seems you have translated parts of the code, which you should not do.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  align-items: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: max-content;
  grid-gap: 140px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px 60px;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="text"] {
  background-color: 4f4f4f;
  color: gray;
  padding: 5px 300px;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
}

aside {
  padding: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

p.a {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#asd {
  text-align: center;
}

#reklambytelekom {
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 100px;
  color: white;
}

#ad {
  margin-right: 115px;
}

.con>* {
  display: inline-block;
}

#fel {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="con">
  <div id="fel"></div>
</div>
<header>
  <div id="img">
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1TR9UwuFvWO7ZAFkYjl9LQ5wNEKpvOzEM" width="200px">
  </div>
  <div id="asd">
    <form><input type="text" name="1" value="Keresés..."></form>
  </div>
</header>
<section>
  <aside>
    <div id="reklambytelekom">
      <p class="a">Remove Ads</p>
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=14CKiNux7_cpRXiM48Sajr7DV0H5ikjFC">
      <div id="ad">
        <p class="a">Ads by Telekom</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </aside>
</section>
```

Comment: try to be neater in writing syntax, it will be very helpful in solving problems.

Learn about grid css or flex display.